# Python Horizontal Floating Stacked Bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization

I like to know how to produce a diagram like the following in Python.
[image]

Which is the best library to use? Seaborn? Pandas? Can anyone point me to some sample code that can produce the diagram.

Answer (score 1):

you can use seaborn for those kind of plots.

the following example code taken from [Here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/horizontal_barplot.html) will plot what you are asking

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

# Initialize the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 15))

# Load the example car crash dataset
crashes = sns.load_dataset("car_crashes").sort_values("total", ascending=False)

# Plot the total crashes
sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
sns.barplot(x="total", y="abbrev", data=crashes,
            label="Total", color="b")

# Plot the crashes where alcohol was involved
sns.set_color_codes("muted")
sns.barplot(x="alcohol", y="abbrev", data=crashes,
            label="Alcohol-involved", color="b")

# Add a legend and informative axis label
ax.legend(ncol=2, loc="lower right", frameon=True)
ax.set(xlim=(0, 24), ylabel="",
       xlabel="Automobile collisions per billion miles")
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
plt.show()
```

If you are looking for different color's just change the `colormap`

Answer (score -1):

Here is some pseudo code, but you can essentially achieve this in pandas. I'm not going to write an entire program for you, but a basic example as you noted should suffice.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.arange(1, 8)

data_frame = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'])


data_frame.plot(kind='barh')



plt.show()
```

This code will create a horizontal bar chart like the one you've shown above. If you want it to be stacked exactly like the one above, you can add the 'stacked=True' argument in the .plot() method. In order to make the bar chart horizontal we pass kind='barh' in the argument. There will automatically be a legend in the chart that highlights what each bar means. You can manipulate the color of the various bars. This is a simple example, and you will have to do more research on pandas, but you can essentially create nice visuals with pandas and matplotlib.pyplot.

Here is the output:
[image]

Again, you can add titles to the values in the DataFrame if you want to get specific names for the columns, and if you have data that supports a stacked bar, simply setting the stacked kwarg to True will create a stacked bar chart for the various categories.